# how to fit border around the ListView when we remove rows?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView that I put a border in XML around it like below:

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

and on a button click, it will add a row to my ListView, and inside every row, I have a delete button, so that row can be deleted.
but when I delete a row, my border, stays the same, and it doesn't fit my new ListView.

another problem is when I delete all of my rows, the border still stays, how can I remove the border entirely when no rows exist?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically change height by using

```
pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(new 
AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: using this, the listview height can be wrapped to the content

Comment: I've tried your way,but it doesn't work and make any difrrence! @Navneet-Krishna

Comment: I used a method to justify the height of my listview! so all I had to do, was to pass my listview to my adapter, and then,use my method to justify the height! thank you sooo much for your time buddy! @ Navneet-Krishna